# Области применения Java

Tags: java

Собственно, скажите, где применяется язык Java? Какой имеет потенциал его изучение?

Comment: язык java активно применяется при обучении языку java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Существует множество областей применения Java, от сайтов электронной коммерции до Android приложений, от научных до финансовых приложений, таких как трейдинговые системы, от игр, типа Minecraft, до настольных программных средств, таких как Eclipse, Netbeans и IntelliJ, от open source фреймворков до J2ME приложений и т.д. Давайте детальнее рассмотрим каждое из них.

**Android приложения**
Если хотите увидеть, где используется Java, не нужно далеко идти. Просто возьмите свой телефон на Android, абсолютно все приложения написаны на Java, с использованием Google и Android API, которые схожи с JDK. Пару лет назад Android предоставил необходимые возможности, благодаря чему сегодня многие Java программисты – Android разработчики. Кстати, Android использует другую JVM и другой и другой способ компановки, но код всё ещё написан на Java.

**Серверные приложения в сфере финансовых услуг**
Java очень обширно применяется в финансовой сфере. Многие мировые инвестиционные банки, типа Goldman Sachs, Citigroup, Barclays, Standard Charted и другие используют Java для написания фронт-энд и бэк-энд офисных электронных систем, систем регулирования и конфирмации, проектов обработки данных и некоторых других. Преимущественно Java используется при написании серверных приложений, в большинстве своём без какого-либо пользовательского интерфейса, которые получают данные с одного сервера, обрабатывают их и отправляют дальше. Java Swing был также популярен для создания «толстоклиентных» интерфейсоф, но сейчас C# быстро захватывает рынок в этой области, а Swing уже выдыхается.

**Вэб-приложения**
Также Java широко используется в электронной коммерции и в области вэб-приложений. Огромное количество RESTful сервисов было создано с использованием Spring MVC, Struts 2.0 и похожих фреймворков. Даже простейшие приложения, основанные на Servlet, JSP и Struts, достаточно популярны в различных государственных проектах. Многие вэб-приложения государственных, оздоровительных, страховых, образовательных, оборонительных и некоторых других отделений написаны на Java.

**Программные средства**
Многие полезные програмные средства и средства разработки написаны и разработаны на Java, например Eclipse, IntelliJ Idea и Netbeans IDE. Мне кажется это, к тому же, наиболее используемые приложения, написанные на Java. Было время, когда Swing был очень популярен при создании «толстых клиентов», преимущественно в финансовой сфере. Сегодня Java FX набирает всё большую популярность, но это всё ещё не замена Swing, к тому же C# практически полностью вытеснил Swing из финансовой области.

**Трейдинговые приложения**
Сторонние трейдинговые приложения, которые также часть большой индустрии финансовых услуг, тоже используют Java. Популярные приложения, типа Murex, которые используются во многих банках, написаны на Java.

**J2ME приложения**
Несмотря на то, что появление iOS и Android практически уничтожило J2ME рынок, в мире ещё огромное количество дешёвых телефонов от Nokia и Samsung, использующих J2ME. Было время, когда практически все игры и приложения, доступные на Android, были написаны с использованием MIDP и CLDC, которые являются частью платформы J2ME. J2ME всё ещё популярен в таких средствах, как Blu-ray, карточки и телевизионные приставки. Одна из причин такой популярности WhatsApp – он также доступен на J2ME.

**Встраиваемые системы**
Обширна Java и в области встраиваемых систем. Можно увидеть на что способна платформа, вам нужно всего 130 KB для использования Java (на смарт-картах и сенсорах). Изначально Java разрабатывалась для встраиваемых систем. В действительности эта область была частью начальной кампании Java «пиши один раз, запускай где-угодно» и похоже, что она приносит свои плоды.

**Большие данные**
Hadoop и другие технологии обработки больших данных так или иначе используют Java, например Hbase и Accumulo от Apache, или ElasticSearch. Хоть Java и не доминирует в этой области, поскольку существуют такие технологии, как MongoDB, которые написаны на С++. У Java есть потенциал получить большую долю этой растущей области, если Hadoop или ElasticSearch расширятся.

**Высокочастотные трейдинговые пространства**
Java улучшила свои эксплуатационные показатели и с современными JIT-ами она способна предоставить производительность на уровне С++. По этой причине Java популярна и при написании высокопроизводительных систем, потому что хоть производительность проигрывает в сравнении с родным языком, но вы можете пожертвовать безопасностью, мобильностью и надёжностью ради большей скорости и требуется всего один неопытный С++ программист, чтобы сделать приложение медленным и ненадёжным.

**Научные приложения**
В наши дни часто Java – выбор по-умолчанию для научных приложений, включая обработку естественного языка. Основная причина в том, что Java более безопасна, мобильна и надёжна и имеет лучшие инструменты параллелизации, чем С++ и другие языки.

Перевод позаимствован из [Где-используется-Java](http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/12/13/%D0%93%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-Java-.html)

Оригинал статьи [Where is Java used in Real World?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ru/2014/12/where-does-java-used-in-real-world.html)

Comment: mongodb и elasticsearch имеют слабое отношение к бигдате

Comment: @Etki Мопед не мой я просто разместил объяву